# Is there a way to access one iframe from another?

Tags: php, iframe

A few details: The two iframes are from different domains. I want to run a script within one iframe, to extract data from another. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods involving the usage of proxies.

Check this out: [Another Cross Domain iFrame Communication Technique](http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx)

For more methods just google "cross domain iframe" you'll find plenty of workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

No direct access - however use intermediate GET/POST or Ajax.